# How to preserve the order of elements in list while converting it to set in Python and how to implement `scanf()` in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Actually I have two questions:

1. How to preserve the order of elements in the list when converted to set?
   For example consider the following:

`>>>set([7, 10, 78, 96, 13, 42, 88, 7, 12, 16])`

`{96, 7, 10, 42, 12, 13, 78, 16, 88}`

The order was lost during conversion. How to preserve the order?

2. How to get input without getting an error when we hit space or enter without actually entering the value?

For example, if the code was like : `n = int(input())` and if the input given was just `<Enter>` but the next line contains the actual input how to wait until a valid input is obtained?

I mean, I want like this as in `C` language. If you write the code like `scanf("%d",&n);` then it will ignore all the spaces and Enter key presses and will get the actual input. Also, there is another feature like getting the time like `scanf("%d:%d", &h, &m);` which actually allows `:` as an input that separates  two different inputs.

I tried the input in two different ways:
First:

```
>>>n = int(input())

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#13>", line 1, in <module>
    n = int(input())
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

Second:

```
>>> from sys import stdin
>>> n = int(stdin.readline())

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#12>", line 1, in <module>
    n = int(stdin.readline())
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '\n'
```

The only noticeable difference is that `stdin` captures the return key while `input()` just captures it as an empty string. But none of them implements the `scanf()` function as explained above. How to implement this?

Comment: if you convert a list without duplicates, it will preserve the order. But if it has duplicates, it'll remove them, so try `set(list(dict.fromkeys([1, 2, 3, 1, 5, 6, 2])))`

Comment: for the second issue, do not convert it to `int` first, just keep giving inputs if the value is `' '`, and when it's not, convert it to int

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to preserve the order you cannot use the `set` object.But you can use `frozenset`.Frozen set is just an immutable version of a Python set object.
So it goes like this,

```
>>> a = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> b = frozenset(a)
>>> print(a)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> print(b)
frozenset({1, 2, 3, 4, 5})
```

For your second issue I suggest using this code.It doesn't break from the loop until an integer is given.

```
>>> while 1:
    try:
        x = int(input().strip())
        break
    except ValueError:
        pass
```

string.strip() is used to remove all leading and trailing whitespaces in a python string.It still works without string.strip() though.
But it doesn't account for any '\n' of string values and loops until an integer is given.

In order to seperate the inputs by the ":" character in them you can simply use `string.split(":")`.It returns a string with the values seperated.

```
>>> a = "1:2:3"
>>> b = a.split(":")
>>> print(b)
['1', '2', '3']
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot @AfiJaabb. I now know where I made the mistake. In the `except` part I again added the same line : `x = int(input())` assuming that it has already passed on to the next line. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Sets do not have an order (or index). Assuming you're converting a list to a set to remove duplicates (and converting it back to a list without sorting), convert the list to NumPy array to remove duplicates.

```
>>> l = [2, 5, 10, 6, 3, 10, 5, 7]
>>> l = np.array(l)    
>>> unique_index = np.unique(l, return_index = True)[-1]
>>> unique_l = [l[i] for i in sorted(unique_index)]
>>> unique_l
[2, 5, 10, 6, 3, 7]
```

Answer (score -1):

#### Use `OrderedSet` from the [ordered-set](https://pypi.org/project/ordered-set/) library.

> An OrderedSet is a mutable data structure that is a hybrid of a list
> and a set. It remembers the order of its entries, and every entry has
> an index number that can be looked up.

First, install ordered-set:

```
pip install ordered-set
```

Example:

```
from ordered_set import OrderedSet

letters = OrderedSet([2, 5, 10, 6, 3, 10, 5, 7])
letters # OrderedSet([2, 5, 10, 6, 3, 7])
```

---

#### Alternatives

If you are converting to a set to remove duplicates, you can use [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict).[`fromkeys`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.fromkeys):

```
from collections import OrderedDict

data = [2, 5, 10, 6, 3, 10, 5, 7]
unique_data = list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(data))
unique_data  # [2, 5, 10, 6, 3, 7]
```

If you want to use set operations, you can append by the order of the unique list checking if it exists on the set:

```
data_intersection = set(unique_data) & {1, 10, 7}
result = [value for value in unique_data if value in data_intersection]
result  # [10, 7]
```

[`dict.fromkeys`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.fromkeys) would work too but key ordering is not guaranteed by specification before Python 3.7.

Comment: Dictionaries are not sets

Comment: The title: "How to preserve the order of elements in list".

Comment: "while converting it to set"

Comment: Yes.  Indeed, they are not. I use a list to show the result. The set is used as an intermediary step which the OP asked for.